# How to change the font size in chart.js according to the screen dimensions

Tags: chart.js

I need to change the font size of the texts in the chart that I created using ‍‍**chart.js** according to the **screen size**, but I don't know how to do it.

I tried to do this with **tailwindcss** and giving a class to the parent tag,but the problem was not solved.

```
<div class="text-md sm:text-lg ">
   <canvas id="chart">
   </canvas>
</div>
```

---

Edit:
The way I solved this problem was by adding `responsive: true` to `options` The problem is solved, but is there a better way?

Answer (score -1):

What have you tried to do other than the suggested?

According to the documentaion the "text-aa" tag controls the font size
Ref: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-size#setting-the-font-size
Eg

```
<div class="text-sm">
    <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Or you can use "text-base", I can't find "text-md" in the documentation?
Please note, "md:text-lg" increases the font size on medium to large screen
md prefix is a medium (screen) query